# Any suggestion for a stable and compatible version of Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, version, compatibility

Ok, there are similar question about this but I'm going a little bit further. I started working with Rails 3.2 but many of the things I wanted to do were not yet compatible. For example I was following the exercises of a book and there were using prototype and effect, things that are deprecated in Rails 3.2, I know I can switch between version, but If you would have to start a serious project and you would like to go through the painless way, which environment would you use?
Rails, Ruby, Prototype or Jquery,coffeescript or js, Sass or css, js.erb or rjs.erb...etc etc...

I know companies that are still using Rails 2.2 because the know exactly the version and their compatibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prototype isn't deprecated, it just isn't the default js library included in Rails 3.1.

Use the `prototype-rails` gem if you want to use prototype.

https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails

If your book was using prototype then it's most likely very out of date.

Here's a great tutorial for Rails 3.2:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2

Comment: Thanks James, but the question was focused more like, Should I make a step backward and adapt to the previous environment or should I move forward and focus to adapt my environment to the newest versions? Sorry if my question was not clear? Thanks

Comment: I say move forward. There is no point in using old software. Bugs have been fixed, new features added, speed is improved, security wholes have been plugged.

Comment: Good to know, Jens, but you know, sometimes it is too hard to deal with all new things, you look for any help online and that issue is still new..., and when things in previous version look so simple, we have to figure it out again... Anyway, let's move forward. Thanks you guys